# Cloudify Script Plugin : Passing inputs as Environment Variables to scripts

Tags: python, cloudify, cloudify-script-plugin

I am trying to pass blueprints inputs as environment variables to a python script (executed by script_plugin during one of the lifecycle operations of a node).

We are using Cloudify 3.1.
My blueprint looks like below (trimmed it to show the required sections):

```
inputs:
  sql_server_username:
    type: string
    default: ''
    description: >
      Enter SQL Server User Name

node_templates:  
  my_install:
      type: my.nodes.Root
      relationships:
        - target: win2012r2
          type: cloudify.relationships. contained_in
      interfaces:
        cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle:
          start:
            implementation: scripts/my/installer.py
            inputs:
                process:
                    env:
                        SQL_USERNAME: { get_input: sql_server_username }
```

and in my python script (installer.py) I am trying to access `SQL_USERNAME` using `os.environ.get("SQL_USERNAME", "DEFAULT")`. But I am always getting the default value even when I pass a custom value via inputs during deploy,

What should I change to be able to access the input parameters as environment vairables (from the inputs section of the blueprint) in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending almost 24 hours, found out that if the script is a python script and eval_script is not set to false in the Process configuration options, the environment variables are not injected (atleast for v 3.1).

Thanks to Dan Kilman. 
The snippet below is from Ref#  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cloudify-users/mEAI9x9ivXQ/39Rg6KgKP4cJ

> They are indeed not exposed as environment variables but are readily
>   available as inputs by placing them in the top level inputs instead of
>   the nested env.process and then doing something like
>
> `from cloudify.state import ctx_parameters as inputs`
>
> afterward, you can access these like this
>
> # inputs in this case is just a sugared dict that allows top level key attribute-like access to the operation inputs
>    # you could just as well do ``` inputs['LOAD_BALANCER_IP'] ``ctx.logger.info(inputs.LOAD_BALANCER_IP) ```

Wish this was explicitly stated in the docs ..